# 8x8 Matrix (max7219): Half of the LEDs permanently on

Tags: led, spi

I am trying to hook up an 8x8 LED matrix to my Raspberry Pi 4B. I connected it to SPI1 because I am already using SPI0 for another device. Here are the pins I am using:

CLK - GPIO 20
CS - GPIO 16
DIN - GPIO 18

According to my readings, this means the device can be controlled through spi port 1 device 2. The issue that I have is that 50% of the LEDs are permanently on. Here is a picture of what it looks like.

https://ibb.co/gmqMjn9

I tried to clear the device using the code below but nothing happens. When I try to display something, only the LEDs that are not permanently on turn on. Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

```
from luma.led_matrix.device import max7219
from luma.core.interface.serial import spi, noop
from luma.core.render import canvas
from luma.core.virtual import viewport
from luma.core.legacy import text, show_message
from luma.core.legacy.font import proportional, CP437_FONT, TINY_FONT, SINCLAIR_FONT, LCD_FONT
serial = spi(port=1, device=2, gpio=noop())
device = max7219(serial, width=8, height=8, block_orientation=-90)

device.hide()
```

Comment: Have you got the matrix round the right way in the sockets on the circuit board behind it? Mount it upside down and you'll get the always on problem.

Comment: It's hard to know because it came already soldered. How can I check?

Comment: Hey, I wanted to thank you. I had not realized that the actual matrix could be switched without desoldering, because the whole thing came in one piece. It now works! I don't know if this is a known thing, but it could help others. If you want to post it as an answer, I will gladly select it.

Comment: I've added that as an answer. Can you tick the accepted answer box.

Comment: Done! Thanks so much, you saved me 10 bucks and some soldering. Glad I did not waste this device. Also, I looked at your pic and I think I recognize you. I saw you help people on different platforms!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch the matrix round. Pull it from the sockets on the circuit board. Turn through 180° and re-insert it. LED matrices have a polarity and it's a common problem to get LEDs lit unexpectedly if the polarity is reversed.